# Help! Amp connection Question

Tags: guitar, amplifiers

Music Stack Exchange!
I have a mini amp head, and I'd like to connect it to a speaker cabinet. However, I have two cabinets; one(Hotone) is too small, and one(Marshall) is too large.
Can I connect my amp head to a solid-state amplifier clean? Won't it blow up or have impedance problem? And if so, how about line out?
Since I'm working on a school band, amp-to-cab mod is out of my choices :(

Comment: Can you add in the brand and model of the mini head and the solid state amp? Then we should be able to tell you the best way to connect them.

Answer (score 1):

You can not connect the speaker output of an amp head into the instrument input of another amplifier without damaging the other amplifier. You can send from the line level out of the amp head into an instrument input, but the tone you get from that may be just the pre-amp of your head, and may not have the tonal qualities of the head itself.